# Dependency Injection in a .NET 6 class project without controllers and HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

When you create a regular .NET 5 or 6 API project, you get some basic classes such as `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs`. I want to replicate that in a class project, because I want to be able to configure my services for dependency injection, but I don't want any controllers or HTTP in my project. As an example, let's assume I want to create a .NET 6 project using minimal API/hosting, and I want to check for file changes in a directory:

**Program.cs**

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
}

static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((_, services) => ConfigureServices(services));

static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTranscient<IFileListener, FileListener>();
}
```

This is probably a good starting point, which is quite similar to `Startup.cs` in an API project.

Inside my `FileListener` class, I want to call a method, that listens for file changes in a folder. Let's call it `StartListening()`. Where would I call that method? At some point I guess I need to do something like:

```cs
var fileListenerService = ((IServiceCollection)services).BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IListener>();
await fileListenerService.StartListening();
```

But where? Inside the `Main` method? Inside `ConfigureServices`? Somewhere else?

Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way, but essentially I just need to call a method and make it run that method until the application is closed.

Comment: Your file listener looks a lot like [hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) so you can implement/register it as one.

Comment: @GuruStron Huh, that's basically what I'm trying to achieve. At the moment I just did the 2 bottom lines of code inside the `ConfigureServices` method, but I don't have to do that using a hosted service. Awesome. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's hosting has a concept of [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) to handle background tasks, so you can turn your `FileListener` into hosted service and register it in DI with `AddHostedService` and the hosting will start it automatically with DI and cancelation signaling support.

Note that consuming scoped services (like EF context with default registration) from the hosted service requires [a little bit extra work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task).